# What `ulimit` value applies to a `systemd` service?

Tags: linux, systemd, file-descriptors

I have a `systemd` service installed. It was creating some problems and I am speculating that it might be file descriptor stuff.

The file descriptor limit `systemd` wide is quite high:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
378259
```

But the soft limit seems to be the default:

```
$ ulimit -Hn
1048576

$ ulimit -Sn
1024
```

Which of these limits applies to my `systemd` service? It is started as a dedicated user:

```
[Unit]
Description=Myservice
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/app
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=app
ExecStart=<PATH>
```

And user `app` is a regular user (`/etc/passwd`):

```
app:x:1002:1002:APP user:/home/app:/bin/sh
```

In other words, what exact number triggers a limit for the `systemd` service I am running, what exact number will result in a failure when an additional fd is opened?

Comment: `ulimit` is user process resource limits, and it does not relate to systemd process. your process (the service) will run based on `user=app` limits.

Comment: Is that the `soft` limit, in the above case, the `1024` number, or the `hard` limit

Comment: for `app` user the limit for `file-descriptors` is 1024 currently (per process), but the user itself can increase it (thats why it's soft). But this can be increase only upto 1048576 (hard limit). If you want to increase it even more than this number, only `root` can increase it (that's why it's hard)

Comment: Gotcha. I should be able to set this via `LimitNOFILE` inside my `systemd` script right?

Comment: You may want to provide it as an answer, seems like that addresses my issues.

Answer (score 0):

`LimitNOFILE` allows specification with a colon:

> Resource limits may be specified in two formats: either as single value to set a specific soft and hard limit to the same value, or as colon-separated pair soft:hard to set both limits individually (e.g. "LimitAS=4G:16G").

But there is a default limit in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`:

```
DefaultLimitCORE=infinity:infinity
```

which take precedence, so if it has soft limit `0` you cannot increase in a unit file...